# Problem with an alignment scenario

Tags: align

I want to align the following results. I want all the terms with an & in front of them to be aligned:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[free-standing-units]{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&\text{result 1} &= 15\dB &+ 20\dB \\
&\text{result 2} &= 15.5\dB &+ 20\dB \\
&\text{result 10} &= 16\dB &+ 20\dB 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

With this implementation, the "=" signs are not aligned. 
I have set an & in front of \text{}, because otherwise result 10 will be displaced.

Comment: you need remove all the `&` at the start  and double the `&` before the `+` but please always post a complete document that allows answers to be tested, not just a fragment. `\dB` is not defined by default , nor is `align` although presumably that's `amsmath`)

Comment: you're right. I have just caught up on that. .. I have also edited the question in that I have changed result 3 to result 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `alignat*` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'alignat*' environment and '\text' macro
\newcommand\dB{\,\mathrm{dB}} % ?
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
&\text{result 1} &&= 15\dB   &{}+ 20\dB \\
&\text{result 2} &&= 15.5\dB &{}+ 20\dB \\
&\text{result 3} &&= 16\dB   &{}+ 20\dB 
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx Mico! What is the difference between alignant and align?

Comment: @Luk - Excerpting from the user guide of the `amsmath` package: "A variant environment `alignat` allows the horizontal space between equations to be explicitly specified. This environment takes one argument, the number of
'equation columns'." (For the example at hand, no extra space is inserted between the first two `&` column indicators.)

Comment: not sure, if I should open a new question: can I write my alignment in two columns as well? So In this example, result 3 would go next to result 1. Is that possible?

Comment: @Luk - Not sure I fully understand your follow-up question, but I think it should be posed as a new question.